# Animating a gif while running background queue

Tags: swift, xcode, background-process, animated-gif

When running this code the spinner gif image is not displayed in the UI until the code in the global queue is executed.

How can the animation be kept visible and animated while the other code is run.
Is this only the case using Appplescript/ASOC?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var progresSpinnerView: NSImageView! 
  @objc dynamic var spinnerImage:NSImage? = nil

  override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.progresSpinnerView.animates = true
    self.spinnerImage =  NSImage(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToResources() + "/" + "Spinner.gif"))
    if let displayName = Bundle.appDisplayName {
        print( "\(displayName) started....")
    }
    self.progresSpinnerView = nil
  }

  @IBAction func loadInfo(_ sender:Any) {
    self.progresSpinnerView.image = self.spinnerImage
    loadFromJob()
    self.progresSpinnerView.image = nil
  }

  func loadFromJob() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync {
        ... run AppleScriptObjc for InDesign
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //update UI
        }

        ... run AppleScriptObjc for InDesign
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //update UI
        }

        ... run AppleScriptObjc for InDesign
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //update UI
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't use `sync` when you dispatch the task on the global queue. Use `async`.

Comment: @Rob's right. If you're using `sync` to run a block, main queue waits until the block finishes execution.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, that was the answer. Still much to learn about queues,  dispatch etc.... For the moment I can carry on.